# Interacting with background view when dialog is open?

Tags: android

I have an Activity, and inside that activity, i have several dialogs popup at unknown times. I would like the user to still be able to interact with the current activity (Press Buttons etc) whilst the dialog is being displayed. Is this possible or would there be an alternative solution to this? I have setup my dialog like so, to prevent it from closing on outside touch:

```
achievDialog = new Dialog(this);
    achievDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    achievDialog.setContentView(R.layout.achiev_get);
    achievDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: It's not possible to do it, at least not to interact as if you would if the View was active view. The only thing you could maybe try, although I'm not even sure if that would work is to use onTouchListener() to catch a drag pattern and then change the values in your view accordingly. But I believe it cannot be done since any click outside the dialog will close it and return to the view.

Comment: Damn. Alright, the dialog is only really supposed to show some information, its not supposed to interfere with the entire program. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: AN alternative would be a popup window i suppose